# page skipped after using centered text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, errors

I'm writing a book on LaTeX but there's this problem - I use this centering text method:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{\Huge The Adventures of Adrian and Co.}
\vfill
\chapter{The Reader is Introduced to a Normal yet not Normal Camping Trip}
\end{document}
```

But a page is skipped after the title:[image: Title]
[image: Skipped page][image: Chapter 1]
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `\documentclass[openany]{memoir}`

Answer (score 3):

The default for chapter openings is `openright` so that each chapter starts on a recto (odd) page. This is what happens in your MWE. You could try the option `openleft` so that chapters all start on verso (even) pages or the `openany` option whereby chapters start on the next page.

```
%\documentclass{memoir}          % chapters start on next odd page
%\documenclass[openleft]{memoir} % chapters start on next even page
%\documentclass[openany]{memoir} % chapters start on next page
```

I'm not sure what you are really trying to achieve in your final output but it seems to me that "Adventures ..." heading is followed by a series of chapters. Maybe later you will have another heading followed by further chapters. Perhaps you might consider using `memoir`s `\book` division (or `\part`).

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\book{The Adventures ...} % or \part{The Adventures ...}
\chapter{The Reader ...}
...
\end{document}
```